# Simplifying on logic Operations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I need simplify the following proposition to 2 logic operations using the laws of the algebra of propositions. Write each step on a separate line with the algebra law you used as a justification.

$(P' \wedge Q') \vee (P' \wedge Q) \vee (P \wedge Q')$

I'm not sure how I could answer this but to start I think maybe using Idempotent law and maybe Associative to solve this. Or maybe I am way off.

Comment: The answer is $(P\wedge Q)'$, if that gives you something to work towards.

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: I'm writing up a solution for you now, but the gist of it is to use DeMorgan's law.

Comment: oh like starting of with ~ (p ∨ q) = ~ p ∧ ~ q

Comment: I was actually using [(p'∧q')∧(p'∧q)]', but your way might work too. Have a go!

Comment: but what was your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(P' \land Q') \lor (P' \land Q) \lor (P \land Q')$$

By identity $A=(A\lor A)$ and associativity:
$${\color{Green} {(P' \land Q')}} \lor (P' \land Q) \lor {\color{Green} {(P' \land Q')}} \lor (P \land Q')$$

By distributivity:
$$(P' \land (Q' \lor Q)) \lor ((P' \lor P) \land Q')$$

Reduction by the law of excluded middle:
$$(P' \land 1) \lor (1 \land Q')$$
and by the neutral element definition:
$$P' \lor Q'$$
Finally de Morgan's law:
$$(P \land Q)'$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $S$ as the universal set. Our given expression is this:

$$(P^\prime\land Q^\prime)\lor (P^\prime \land Q)\lor (P\land Q^\prime)$$

Use the converse of distributive laws along with associativity laws to reduce the given expression as:

$$\left\{P^\prime \land (Q^\prime \lor Q)\right\}\lor (P\land Q^\prime)=\{P^\prime \land S\}\lor (P\land Q^\prime)=P^\prime\lor (P\land Q^\prime)$$

$$P^\prime\lor(P\land Q^\prime)=(P^\prime\lor P)\land (P^\prime\lor Q^\prime)=S\land (P^\prime\lor Q^\prime)=P^\prime \lor Q^\prime$$

Using De-Morgan's law, we get,

$$P^\prime \lor Q^\prime = (P\land Q)^\prime$$

We also used the following laws:

- $S=P\lor P^\prime = Q\lor Q^\prime$
- $Q=Q\land S~~,~~P=P\land S$

Comment: so you only used Distributive law and Associative law to simplify it, but what are those extra laws you used?

Comment: @PatrickWilliamMcCully, the places where I introduced $S$ and then finally eliminated it in the simplification process used those laws. Precisely speaking, I used them in the 2nd and 4th steps.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas but equally... $$\left\{Q^\prime \land (P^\prime \lor P)\right\}\lor (Q\land P^\prime)=\{Q^\prime \land S\}\lor (Q\land P^\prime)=(Q^\prime \lor Q)\land P^\prime=S\land P^\prime = P^\prime$$ see the problem? After all, the term is symmetrical, swap the P's and Q's and it's the same expression...

Comment: this is starting to make sense.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall, I think I spotted an error in my answer. Let me edit it. Wait a minute.